# Getting json data from a webpage using PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, steam-web-api

I am trying to fetch a response from [here (example url)](https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=SG%20553%20%7C%20Damascus%20Steel%20(Factory%20New)), and first, I thought I should use file_get_contents()

When I tried this, I got the following error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&amp;currency=1&amp;appid=730&amp;market_hash_name=SG%20553%20|%20Damascus%20Steel%20(Factory%20New)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

I know this is because it is converting & to `&amp;`. I have tried numerous ways to counter this, however they have all failed and after a quick google I came to the conclusion that file_get_contents() converts & to `&amp;` automatically.

My next step was to try curl. I tried the below code first:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name='.$hash,
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) ChromePlus/4.0.222.3 Chrome/4.0.222.3 Safari/532.2'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

But this returned `‹ŠŽÿÿ)»L` as the response. I wondered if this was to do with json encoding, so I tried putting it through json_decode() but it didn't work.

Next, I tried:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) ChromePlus/4.0.222.3 Chrome/4.0.222.3 Safari/532.2',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        country => "US",
        currency => 1,
        appid => 730,
        market_hash_name => "SG%20553%20|%20Damascus%20Steel%20(Factory%20New)"
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

But again got the response `‹ŠŽÿÿ)»L`.

What does this response mean, and can I parse it? If not, how should I correctly fetch this data? Furthermore, why didn't file_get_contents() work?

Comment: Do you need some type of access token to access the steam web API?

Comment: As it turns out you must be signed into Steam in order to access the priceoverview - which is different to most of the API, which requires an API key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is happening because you need some type of access token to access the steam web API.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110396/2624391) on SO.

Essentially, Steam is returning an error with the "400 Bad Request" status. This error can be ignored, however, by doing this:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=SG%20553%20%7C%20Damascus%20Steel%20(Factory%20New)";
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
      'http' => array(
          'ignore_errors'=>true,
          'method'=>'GET'
          // for more options check http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php
        )
    ));
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo $response; // returns "[]"
?>
```

Make sure you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16110396/2624391) on SO.

Comment: You do for normal web api requests, however not for Steam Market requests (try visiting the link in your browser)

Comment: Then I'm not sure why Steam is returning the "400 Bad Request" error, but either way the error can be ignored by setting `ignore_errors` to `true`, which appears to fix the problem.

Comment: It returns [], you are correct. However, the webpage is substantially more than that. Any ideas?

Comment: It is? Viewing https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=SG%20553%20%7C%20Damascus%20Steel%20(Factory%20New) in my browser, I just get `[]` (which is what PHP also returns).

Comment: Yes, please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32129984/4907685), seems steam requires you to be signed in, which I was, so I was seeing a completely different page to you

Answer (score 1):

May be your response is gzip, try to use CURLOPT_ENCODING.

`curl_setopt($curl ,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '')`

If you use https don't forget to disable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`

One thing, if I follow your link with my browser and open my debug console.
I see you request have a 400 Status code (Bad Request).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cant say about your enpoint, but you can get around your Bad Request error by using `urlencode()`:

```
$url = urlencode('https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory/?country=US&currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=SG%20553%20%7C%20Damascus%20Steel%20(Factory%20New))'
file_get_contencts($url);
```

Comment: I have already tried this, also, it fixes nothing. The correct things are already encoded and depending on what else you encode you either get the same error as me, or php fails to recognise the URL