# PHP file_get_contents returns with a 400 Error

Tags: php, json

My problem is pretty straightforward, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I've done something similar with another API, but this just hates me.

Basically, I'm trying to get information from https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob and use the JSON result to get basic information on the user. But whenever I try to use file_get_contents, it just returns

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST in Z:\DevProjects\Client Work\Overwatch Boost\dashboard.php on line
```

So I don't know what's wrong, exactly. My code can be seen here:

```
$apiBaseURL = "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u";
$apiUserInfo = $gUsername;
$apiFullURL = $apiBaseURL.'/'.$apiUserInfo.'/blob';

$apiGetFile = file_get_contents($apiFullURL);
```

Any help would be largely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you echo $apiFullURL right before you call file_get_contents?

Comment: your missing some headers it expects (at a guess), tested locally same result, try curl()

Comment: 400 is a bad request error meaning you are likely not providing headers or additional data the request is expecting

Comment: @vicatcu Yes, it echos "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Get Content of HTTP 400 Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710147/php-get-content-of-http-400-response)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set user agent for file_get_contents like this, and you can check it with this code. Refer to **[this](https://joshtronic.com/2013/06/04/specifying-a-user-agent-when-using-file_get_contents/)** for set user agent for file_get_contents.

```
<?php
$options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0'));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents('https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob', false, $context);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: how is that different from what the OP did, if $gUsername = "Xvs-1176"?

Comment: @vicatcu I've edit it and checked it.   You can check it now. Thans for your comment.

Comment: As @vicatcu states, it definitely was the header issue. Thank you both so much for your answers :D

Answer (score 1):

That's what page is sending: "Hi! To prevent abuse of this service, it is required that you customize your user agent".
You can customize it using curl like that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);   

$output = json_decode($output);

if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
  var_dump($output);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: All I get returned is "Z:\DevProjects\Client Work\Overwatch Boost\dashboard.php:89:" and null.

Comment: @SDC Oh, yes, you gotta use the $output variable

Comment: @SDC just print_r($output);

Comment: @SDC I decoded json for you already when did the $output = json_decode($output). If it's not your desired behaviour, remove this string.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `curl -v https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob` you will get a response *and* you will see what headers cURL includes by default. Namely:

```
> Host: owapi.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
```

So then the question is, which one does owapi care about? Well, you can stop cURL from sending the default headers like so:

```
curl -H "Accept:" -H "User-Agent:" -H "Host:" https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob
```

... and you will indeed get a 400 response. Experimentally, here's what you get back if you leave off the "Host" or "User-Agent" headers:

```
{"_request": {"api_ver": 3, "route": "/api/v3/u/Xvs-1176/blob"}, "error": 400, "msg": "Hi! To prevent abuse of this service, it is required that you customize your user agent."}
```

You actually don't need the "Accept" header, as it turns out. See the PHP [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) on how to send headers along with file_get_contents.